# How does one validate submission-time values?

Tags: infosphere-spl

SPL supports [submission-time values](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/streams/v3r1/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.streams.spl-compiler-usage-reference.doc/doc/submissionvalues.html), which are retrieved via function calls getSubmissionTimeValue() and/or getSubmissionTimeListValue().  Since there is no `main()` function in an SPL program, how can I validate these values in an operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `param` clause or `logic state` clause, assign a variable via means of an SPL function.  Perform your validation in the SPL function.

```
stream<blob incoming_data, uint32 source_port> DataStream
as UDPReceiver = UDPSource() {
   param
      address : getConfig('exporter'); // IP address or host name
```

```
stream<blob incoming_data, uint32 source_port> NextStream
as Parser = Custom(DataStream) {
   logic
      state: {
          MyInfoMap _my_info_map = getInfoAsMap();
```

Above, SPL functions getConfig() and getInfoAsMap() would retrieve the submission-time values and validate them.